# Live video feed error message in simulink

Tags: simulink

I tried to run a live video feed using simulink and after connecting the "from video device" block to the "display" block and running it, I received this message

Truncating signals shown by 'untitled/Display'.  Displays can only show at most 200 elements of a vector or [20x10] elements of a matrix signal

Can you guys help me fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You should use something like "Video Viewer" block to see the video feed. Display block is used to see raw numbers and is limited to showing smaller set of input data if it is large.

The Video Viewer block is available with Computer Vision System toolbox in the Sinks library.